# javascript spilt to get part of the word

Tags: javascript

I tried use javascript spilt to get part of the word : `new` from `What#a_new%20day`

I tried code like this:

```
<script>
var word="What#a_new%20day";
var newword = word.split("%20", 1).split("_", 2);
alert(newword);
</script>
```

But caused:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object What#a_new has no method 'split'`

Maybe there have more wiser way to get the word which I need. So can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What's the general problem you're trying to solve? This is a pretty specific example, so you're likely to get a lot of specific responses that won't necessarily solve the general problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an array, so the second `split` is trying to operate on the array returned by the first, rather than a string, which causes a TypeError. You'll also want to add the correct index after the second call to `split`, or `newword` will also be an array, not the String you're expecting. Change it to:

```
var newword = word.split("%20", 1)[0].split("_", 2)[1];
```

This splits `word`, then splits the string at index 0 of the resulting array, and assigns the value of the string at index 1 of the new array to `newword`.

Answer (score 2):

Regex to the rescue

```
var word="What#a_new%20day";
var newword = word.match(/_(.+)%/)[1];
alert(newword);
```

this returns the first (`[1]`) captured group (`(...)`) in the regex (`_(.+)%`) which is `_` followed by any character (`.`) one or more times (`+`) followed by `%`.

Comment: +1 for providing an answer that's likely to be more useful in general.

Answer (score 1):

split returns an array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

word.split("%20", 1);

gives an array so you cannot do :

(result from above).split("_", 2);

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools. It is not a good resource to learn anything. See http://w3fools.com. Here is the equivalent MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

the result of a split is an array, not a string. so what you need to do is

```
<script>
var word="What#a_new%20day";
var newword = word.split("%20", 1)[0].split("_", 2);
alert(newword);
</script>
```

notice the **[0]**

Answer (score 1):

If split is what your after, go for it, but performance wise, it would be better to do something like this:

```
var word="What#a_new%20day";
var newword = word.substr(word.indexOf('new'),3)
alert(newword);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qJ8wM/

Split searches for all instances of `%20` in the text, whereas indexOf finds the first instance, and substr is fairly cheap performance wise as well.

JsPerf stats on split vs substring (a general case): http://jsperf.com/split-vs-substring